# Grails case insensitive URL Mapping of predefined URL?

Tags: grails

I have the following url mapping:

```
  "/Some-Name".toLowerCase() {
    controller ="user"
    action = "show"
    id = "f274b72e1309467e70"
  }
```

Note this is not a duplicate of this: [How to make my URL mapping case insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809588/how-to-make-my-url-mapping-case-insensitive) It is a different case.

**How can I make this URL mapping case insensitive?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to use custom validator in constraint section. Please note that code below is not tested.

```
   "/$path" {
      controller ="user"
      action = "show"
      id = "f274b72e1309467e70"
      constraints {
         path((validator: { return it.equalsIgnoreCase("Some-Name") })
      }
   }
```

Comment: What is path in your constraint?

Comment: path is variable from mapping `/$path`, you can see [similar use case here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356916/adding-urlmapping-constraints-to-a-verb-mapped-url)